# New property in document goes to the bottom in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Maybe I'm nitpicking here but I'd like to keep my `documents` nice and organized in my `Cosmos DB` collection.

I set the order of my object's properties in my `DAO classes` -- see below:

```
public class MyObject
{
   [JsonProperty("id", Order = 1)]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("firstName", Order = 2)]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("lastName", Order = 3)]
   public string LastName { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("email", Order = 4)]
   public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

The issue I'm seeing is that if I add a new property to my object and save it as a `document` in `Cosmos DB`, the new property seems to be inserted at the bottom, regardless of the order I set for it in my `DAO object`.

Say, I add a date of birth property as below:

```
public class MyObject
{
   [JsonProperty("id", Order = 1)]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("firstName", Order = 2)]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("lastName", Order = 3)]
   public string LastName { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("dob", Order = 4)]
   public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("email", Order = 5)]
   public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

When I check my document in Data Explorer in Azure Portal, here's what I see:

```
{
   "id": "23b03604-bf35-43bb-895f-a208d3df0847",
   "firstName": "Jane",
   "lastName: "Doe",
   "email": "me@me.com",
    "_rid": "bf0eAMcH2wAXAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/bf0eAA==/colls/bf0eAMcH2wA=/docs/bf0eAMcH2wAXAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"09001cb6-0000-0000-0000-5adc25130000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "dob": "1991-02-08T00:00:000.0000000Z",
    "_ts": 1524376851
}
```

Even though this doesn't seem to have any affect in my ability to run queries, I'd like to keep the document structure same as in my `DAO object`.

Is there a way for me to make sure the order of my properties are preserved as I add new ones into my documents?

Comment: Have you done any test to make sure that the Order property is taken into account in CosmosDB sdk? The file metadata (_rid,_ts) dont have one as far as i know so it might be the reason why it's ignored. Try shuffling the line order in your dao without changing the order property and see what happens.

Comment: I know for sure that Cosmos DB SDK honors the order.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is happening because when I add a new property I'm not replacing the whole document. I think if I were to perform a replace, the order would be correct. Also I have a feeling that a complete replace would cost more RU's.

Comment: Just did a test. The request charge for Replace and Upsert was exactly the same. Are you using Upsert?